# <a> element not working properly when hiding parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

I made this script, and despite one oddity, it works fine. It's hiding/showing the parent of div element with a class containing specific content. The problem when I press my `<a>` elements, that act as buttons, they "filter" the divs, but it leaves the first comment `<a>`? If I change the element do a `<div>` instead no problem, but with an `<a>` element it behaves weirdly? Is this just a bug or?

here is a **JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/g1puxhs7/2/

**HTML:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<a class='viewBtn'>Published<a>
<a class='viewBtn'>Completed<a>
<a class='viewBtn'>Created<a>


<div class="orders" id="orders">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="status">
        Completed
        </div>
        <a>Comment</a>
  </div>

       <div class="row">
        <div class="status">
        Completed
        </div>
        <a>Comment</a>
  </div>

       <div class="row">
        <div class="status">
        Completed
        </div>
        <a>Comment</a>
        </div>
   </div>

   <style>
   .row {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;  
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 4px;
  }
 </style>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
//--Filter by Status--//
$('.viewBtn').click(function() {
var txt = $(this).text();
  $('.status:contains("' + txt + '")').parent().toggle();
$(this).toggleClass('down');
});
```

Comment: Your HTML markup is not valid, check it again

Comment: Perhaps you're having an off day, but next time this can easily be checked with any HTML validator, whether it's built into NotePad++, Sublime Text, or any IDE or online HTML validator script. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your links:

```
<a class='viewBtn'>Published<a>
<a class='viewBtn'>Completed<a>
<a class='viewBtn'>Created<a>
```

You have 6 opening `a` tags, instead of 3 opening and 3 closing tags.

This is why the browser adds closing `a` tags in your script in a bunch of places, one of them in your first `div`—and then your whole DOM tree looks different than what you want.

Comment: Wow, let's all agree that I am an idiot. It's been a really long day xD, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your markup needed to be cleaned up. Here is your markup cleaned up. Also, i find it best to add href for you anchor tags, and then you can comment them out with #, or you can add javascript:void(0). If you use the # approach, in your JS, you can add e.preventDefault();

HTML Cleaned:

```
<div>
    <a class='viewBtn' href="#">Published</a>
    <a class='viewBtn' href="#">Completed</a>
    <a class='viewBtn' href="#">Created</a>
</div>

<div class="orders" id="orders">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="status">
        Completed
        </div>
        <a class="stuff" onclick="Comment">Comment</a>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="status">
        Completed
        </div>
        <a class="stuff">Comment</a>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="status">
        Completed
        </div>
        <a class="stuff">Comment</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS with preventDefault():

```
$('.viewBtn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var txt = $(this).text();
    $('.status:contains("' + txt + '")').parent().toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('down');
});
```